# powerline-networking: counteract dissipation 3500 sq ft structure

Tags: internet-connection, powerline-networking, interference, signal-strength

I've plugged-in two TP-LINK - Powerline AV500 Nano Adapters . Router is apprx 100' from the Fios box via Cat5e cable. Tests 70 MBPs as promised at router.

The home office is on the other side of the house, 30 MBPS via Wifi. Second TP-Link node gets only 4 MBPS via the power line connection. The devices state they can work on 1000' of powerline...given the post I found below, I'm guessing this solution can't work for anything other than a VERY small structure?!! Seems odd...

"1200 square foot 4 room home, we used about 2500 feet of wire" https://www.houzz.com/discussions/2650073/feet-of-wire-to-wire-home

Any bright ideas on how I can get internet of at least 20MBPS (of my 70mbps) flowing thru all of my 3500 sq foot home?

Comment: A true Cat5 or Cat6 wired connection is simply going to be more reliable and outperform anything else you could come up with. It may be a pain, but getting some cabling to other parts of the house is the best solution. You can then expand your WiFi coverage with some sort of wireless mesh system. It doesn’t have to be hard to run networking cable. It can be difficult to make it nice and clean and get it through the walls, but your alternative can be what many ISPs do, and that is drill a hole through the wall and run the wire outside. Two strategically placed access points would probably work.

Comment: Blows my mind that information can travel for hundreds (or thousands) of miles incredibly quickly without issue -- but can't traverse a few thousand feet of wire within a house...

Comment: Also realizing that someone good with cabling can likely use the old phone lines to pull Cat5 throughout the house (and dump the phone lines that won't really be needed anymore, eh!

Comment: Good point, but those signals that travel thousands of miles use the proper technology to do so. Power line Ethernet is kind of a hack. :)